# hashmap keyset automatically sorted

Tags: java, hashmap

```
    HashMap<String, String[]> content = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    content.put("Help", new String[]{"About"});
    content.put("View", new String[]{"Grid"});
    content.put("File", new String[]{"Import", "Export"});

    for(String key : content.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

The above code logs:

```
View
Help
File
```

But why is this sorted?

Comment: Run it twice, thrice, more.. You would see different results.

Comment: By chance. Add more keys and you'll see it is not sorted.

Comment: Restarted 10 times, but always the same order.

Comment: Even if its sorted every time, its not _guaranteed_ to be sorted so you shouldn't rely on it.  There are probably plenty of behaviors that just _happen to be_, but if they aren't part of the documentation/API/contract, then you shouldn't rely on them.

Comment: There are just 6 ways to order 3 different items. Two of those are sorted. 1 in 3 chance is hardly rare.

Comment: You may run very,very many times your code and the order will be the same because it depends on two factors - KEY's hashCode and length of backing array. Whenever you cause backing array of HashMap to grow you LOSE the order. Please cover my tutorial [Internal life of HashMap](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashmap-in-java.html)

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Your link is broken, but I was able to find it in web archives. See [Internal life of HashMap](http://web.archive.org/web/20130811002118/http://volodial.blogspot.in/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashmap-in-java.html). It was awesome, thanks for that!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. HashMap makes absolutely no guarantees about the iteration order. It can (and will) even change completely when new elements are added.
2. LinkedHashMap will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: About 2 statement. You may create LinkedHashMap that will iterate by access-order but not insertion-order. Insertion-order is only default one.

Answer (score 4):

The order in which you see the entries in the `HashMap` depends on the hash codes of the keys and order of the entries in the bucket I believe and it is implementation dependent, but don't rely on `HashMap` for ordering at all. Whereas `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` do guarantee a certain order.